# Reactivity towards nucleophillic addition

Tags: nucleophilicity

1. Phenyl ethanal or ethanal

I thought phenyl methanal is less reactive towards nucleophilic attack due to presence of bulky group. But answer in my book suggest ethanal is less reactive.

2. *Para*-methoxybenzaldehyde vs *para*-methylbenzaldehyde.

in this case due to the prescence of $\ce{OCH3}$ $\ce{O}$ will act as an electron withdrawing group as well as electron donating (resonace) whereas $\ce{CH3}$ group will only donate it's electron (resonance) thus *para*-methoxybenzaldehyde  should be more reactive. Again, the answer in my book states *para*-methylbenzaldehyde is more reactive.

Comment: The resonance effect of the methoxy group (donation of electrons) is more important than its inductive effect and the resonance effect of the methoxy group overwhelms the donation effect of the methyl group. Thus, your book is correct. [BTW: By phenyl methanal do you mean benzaldehyde? Ethanal (acetaldehyde) should be more reactive toward nucleophiles than benzaldehyde owing to resonance contribution from the phenyl ring.]

Comment: i meant phenyl  ethanl benzene with ch2-cho

Comment: I think you mean phenylacetaldehyde. As to my previous comments, you might look at: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110641/nucleophilic-addition-propanal-vs-benzaldehyde?rq=1